# vimdiff files given in a text file

Tags: bash, diff

I have a text file `files.txt` with following entries

```
"/home/dilawar/a.txt","/home/dilawar/b.txt"
"/home/dilawar/aa.txt","/home/dilawar/bb.txt"
```

Now I wish to see the `diff` of files on line 1. I tried the following

```
head -n 1 files.txt | cut -d, -f 2,3 | sed "s/,/\t/g" | xargs -I files vimdiff files
```

It is not working. I replaced vimdiff with diff, it did not work either. However this works

```
head -n 1 files.txt | cut -d, -f 1 | xargs -I file vim file
```

How to pass `file` as an argument to diff as two separate file paths rather than a single string?

PS : To make matter worse, I have space in some of file paths.

Answer (score 1):

First take the first line, then recplace the symbols by a space, and feed it to `vimdiff` via a subshell.

```
 vimdiff $(head -1 files.txt | tr '",' ' ')
```

The above elegant method will not work with names with a space. The below dirty one will.

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print "vimdiff",$1,$2}' files.txt | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, see if it helps

```
sed '1{s/,/ /; s/^/diff /;q}' files.txt|sh
```

Comment: `/home/dilawar/Works/hpc21/2013ee668/Assignments/A4/Submissions/KAMLESH AGRAWAL/Question2/test_bench.vhdl,/home/dilawar/Works/hpc21/2013ee668/Assignments/A4/Submissions/SHARDUL GAUR/09D07039_asgn4/gcd/test_bench.vhd : No such file or directory.` Only if I can remove that `,` between the name of two files? It is taking it as single file.

Answer (score 0):

I also escaped the whitespace in filepath (first sed command)

```
 head -n 1 files.txt | sed "s/ /\\\\ /g" | sed "s/[\",]/ /g" |xargs vimdiff
```